# fetch data from Laravel with Vue Cli => Error 500

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, fetch

I have a laravel project where i store my data. I want to get this data in my Vue frontend using fetch. But while im trying im getting an Error 500. Why?

This is my mounted function in Vue

```
mounted(){
fetch("/api/items")
.then((response)=>response.text())
.then((data)=>{
this.msg = JSON.parse(data);
{
```

Get Function in Laravel

```
public function index()
{
    return Item::orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get();
}
```

Post function in Laravel

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $newItem = new Item;
    $newItem->name = $request->item["name"];
    $newItem->save();
    return $newItem;
}
```

my Routes

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request 
$request) {
return $request->user();
});

Route::get('/items', [ItemController::class, 'index']);
Route::prefix('/item')->group(function(){
Route::post('/store', [ItemController::class, 'store']);
Route::put('/{id}', [ItemController::class, 'update']);
Route::delete('/{id}', [ItemController::class, 'destroy']);
});
```

[the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Jlul.png)

I tried it with postman to check if its on my Server or frontend. There i have no problems
[Post in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcNvd.png)
[Get in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTbei.png)

Comment: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Please [edit] your question to include the text.

Comment: Looks like your route returned the text `Proxy error`, instead of actual JSON ...

Comment: Did you check what is the error 500? check the laravel logs or the network tab if you have debug enabled.